# Как передать значение выбранного radio в атрибут formaction кнопки?

Tags: javascript, php, form, radio-input

Есть несколько флажков с разными value. Есть три кнопки submit. Нужно при выборе флажка, передать его value на все три кнопки submit:

```
<input type="submit" value="Туда" formaction="/tuda/$значение">
<input type="submit" value="Сюда" formaction="/suda/$значение">
<input type="submit" value="Обратно" formaction="/obratno/$значение">
```

и надо чтобы отправлялось постом, а не гетом

Я пробовала всякие решения из сети, но нифига они не работают ))))

Вот так никак

```
<input type="radio" name="test" value="<?= $value['id'] ?>" />

<?php if($_POST["test"]) { $test = $_POST["test"];}

var_dump($test); // вывод null

?>

<input type="submit" formaction="/tuda/<?= $test ?>" value="Туда" />
```

Я так поняла, что до отправки не получить, а как джаваскриптом это всё реализовать?

Даже если отправлять get-ом. То как очистить перед отправкой строку? Нужно убрать из неё всё, кроме цифр. Например, `?test=2` чистим до `2`.

Вот так работает:

```
var allcheckbox = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
        function sending_2(){
            var out = "";
            for(i = 0; i < allcheckbox.length - 1; i ++) if(allcheckbox[i].checked)out += "-or-" + allcheckbox[i].value;
            location.href = "/tuda/" + "" + out.substring(4);
        }

        function sending_1(){
            var out = "";
            for(i = 0; i < allcheckbox.length - 1; i ++) if(allcheckbox[i].checked)out += "-or-" + allcheckbox[i].value;
            location.href = "/suda/" + "" + out.substring(4);
        }

<input type="submit" formaction="" value="Туда" onclick="sending_1(); return false" />
    <input type="submit" formaction="" value="Сюда" onclick="sending_2(); return false" />
```

Но это же коряво и вообще костыль. Как нормально то сделать?

Comment: У вас всё напутано. Советую прочитать: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/tutorial.forms.php

Comment: @YaMus, да там не напутано. Просто мне нужно чтобы значение выбранного флажка передавалось в атрибут formaction. И я так понимаю, что это невозможно реализовать средствами php, потому что это происходит на клиенте. Мне просто нужно решение на javascript. В мануале не написано как получить до отправки $_POST, потому что это не реализуемо

Comment: Передай флажок на сервер и там уже решай что делать.

Comment: @u_mulder, а зачем? Можно же просто передать значение в атрибут джаваскриптом. Смысл всего этого примерно такой: чел открывает таблицу, там кликабельные строки, выбирает строку и потом выбирает кнопку действия, что можно сделать с этой строкой